# How to sync jupyter notebooks with Databricks workspace and see files already in the Databricks workspace using new Databricks extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, databricks

Yesterday Databricks unveiled their new [VSCode extension](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2023/02/14/announcing-a-native-visual-studio-code-experience-for-databricks.html). Although [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paiqo.databricks-vscode) was already available thanks to paiqo, integration between Databricks and VSCode was sometimes difficult to work with. The new integration works perfectly, but I cannot seem to sync jupyter notebook to my workspace only python scripts, in the Paiqo's extensions this is however possible.  Also, I cannot work on files already in the repo, only on files I create locally. In Paiqo's extension this is also possible.

Now I wonder if it is possible to sync jupyter notebooks with Databricks workspace and see files already in the Databricks workspace from VSCode using the new extension?

- I tried syncing using py scripts and ipynb scripts and only the ipynb fail to sync.

Comment: It's better to file this as an issue at https://github.com/databricks/databricks-vscode/issues